# Как сделать событие по нажатию (бинды) java awt robot

Tags: java

У меня есть вот-такая программа:

```
Robot rbt = new Robot();
    
    rbt.mouseMove(50, 70);
    System.out.println(rbt.getPixelColor(50, 70));
    }
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы когда я нажал клавишу F12, она начала свою работу ?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте этот отрыв кода

```
Action doNothing = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
};
component.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F12"),
                            "doNothing");
component.getActionMap().put("doNothing",
                             doNothing);
```

Comment: Что обозначает "doSomething"?

Comment: Прошу прощение не полный код написал.  Изменил ответ